# Breaking a while loop for a secondary reason

Tags: python, break

I am creating a roulette game, this is what I have so far, the problem arises in the fact that the game I have created allows "cash" to go below the bet. I tried to add a bet > cash , break but that didn't change anything any help appreciated

```
import random

bet = 1
cash = 100
counter = 1
result_1 = random.randint(1,10)

print ('Starting money £', cash) ;

if result_1 < 5:
    cash = cash + bet 

while (result_1 > 4):
    cash = cash - bet
    print ('Loss' ,counter, 'you have £', cash)
    counter = counter + 1
    result_1 = random.randint(1,10)
    bet = bet * 3
    if result_1 < 4:
        cash = cash + bet
    if cash < bet:
        break

print ('You won! Your money is: £', cash - 1 + bet)

if counter == 1:
    print ('It took you ', counter, 'attempt to win')

else:
    print ('It took you ', counter, 'attempts to win')  

print ('your largest bet was £' , bet)
```

Comment: Where you are trying to break? I cannot see any. Can you post the expected behavior as well?

Comment: I removed the break because it didn't change anything, the intended break occurs within the while loop, because it runs, if loss occurs, trebles bet and runs again until a win, however I am trying to break the loop when the bet becomes bigger than the amount of cash, to try and make bet < cash at all times

Comment: Well it depends where did you try to break. Unless you show the code we really can't help you

Comment: have updated the code, it didnt do anything in my testing

Comment: It is very confusing as you have an random number generator in the code. Well syntactically your code seems fine. SO what is your expected result?

Comment: the expected out come is to not allow a bet of 81, which would occur on the fifth iteration of the loop, however this limitation does not apply

Comment: the idea of the whole system is that you have 100 cash, and starting bet of 1, the roulette game has odds of winning of 4/9 and loss of 5/9, when you lose, the bet gets x3, so the bets are 1,3,9,27,81. The system doesn't work however as a bet of 81 shouldn't be allowed as the accumulation of the previous bets makes the cash balance below 81